# Determine if the following series is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Determine if the following series is convergent:

$$\sum_n^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + \cos \pi n}$$.

Comment: Looks a lot like just $\sum{1\over n^2}$.

Comment: What is $\pm1$ compared to $n^2$ for large $n$? Nothing so see above comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n^2 + \cos n\pi \geq n^2 - 1 \geq 0.5n^2$  for $n \geq 2$. So:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2 + \cos n\pi} < \displaystyle \sum_{n=2}^\infty \dfrac{2}{n^2}.$$

By comparison test, the series converges.

Answer (score 2):

$\dfrac{1}{n^2-1}\geqslant\dfrac{1}{n^2+\cos\pi n}$

So, if $\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2-1}$ then $\sum\dfrac{1}{n^2+\cos\pi n}$ converges.

Now, by Cauchy Condensations Test, if $\sum\dfrac{2^n}{2^{2n}-1}$ converges, the sum converges.

$\dfrac{2^n}{2^{2n}-1}=\dfrac{2^n}{(2^n+1)(2^n-1)}<\dfrac{1}{2^n-1}$

We know that $\sum\dfrac{1}{2^n-1}$ converges.

Hence, converges.